# Prevent flash opening new windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

Is there anyway to prevent flash files (swf) that are embeded within a webpage from opening a browser window? Eg. prevent the links within a flash file from opening new windows.

Possibly with javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 1):

There will not be a way for that. you have to at least allow some flash vars to control the link targets so you can access it with javascript